# Does the difference in the height of artificial lighting affects the height of the plants?

Tags: botany, book-recommendation, plant-perception

I have some plants living on artificial lighting. I've noticed the following in the following two plants of the same species:

This one was grown with lamps very close to it (~10cm).

> [image]

This one was grown with lamps far away from it (~1m).

> [image]

The first one got smaller while the second one is much taller. It seems that at least for some plants, the difference of height in lighting affects the height of the plants/speed of growth/etc. As soon as I changed the first plant to a place with higher light, it seemed to grow (vertically) much faster. If that is true, I guess someone already noticed it. I'd like to read more about it, could you point me to references on this?

Comment: Don't forget that you have a sample size of 1. You therefore can conclude much from this "experiment". The difference can be due to soil differences or aeration. Also, the two plants are of the same species but they are not clones. There might well be genetic predisposition.

Comment: @Remi.b Yes, I did not conclude anything. It wouldn't make sense to conclude by asking if it is true.